# Can I extend the DB library of CodeIgniter 2?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to add custom data to the insert method of the db library to automatically do some timestamp work and other processing. I know I can extend controller and model defaults with MY_, but what about the DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isnt the right answer, because you can extend your CI Database class, i did it!
Just follow this tut and you will get it working!

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers

im just have problems trying to use two database connections when the second connection is loaded with $this->db->load(), just had this problem, everyelse work like a charm!

Comment: Link has changed: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers

Answer (score 2):

No: see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html, there is an explicit warning that the DB class can't be extended.

Comment: Well, you should be able to provide a wrapper function that just invokes the underlying DB class, no?